# Avalonia Canvas: ItemControl do not set Canvas.Top or Canvas.Left

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm using Avalonia 11 and trying to draw shapes on a Canvas using ItemsControl. **The problem is that the properties Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top are not being taken into account.**

**View:**

```xml
<Canvas Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="100" Background="Yellow" Margin="3">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="10" Width="10" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="{Binding Size}" Width="{Binding Size}" 
                           Canvas.Left="{Binding TopY}" Canvas.Top="{Binding TopY}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public record CanvasTile(int Size, int TopX, int TopY);

public ObservableCollection<CanvasTile> Tiles { get; }

Tiles.Add(new CanvasTile(TILE_SIZE, 1 * TILE_SIZE, 1 * TILE_SIZE));
Tiles.Add(new CanvasTile(TILE_SIZE, 2 * TILE_SIZE, 2 * TILE_SIZE));
Tiles.Add(new CanvasTile(TILE_SIZE, 4 * TILE_SIZE, 4 * TILE_SIZE));
```

**Debug**

[image]

**Result**
As you can see the green rectangles defined by the ItemControl are not at the right place. The blue rectangle is at the right place (I hardcoded his position outside of the  (see code above)

[image]

**Expected Result**
I've hardcoded the expected result to show what I should have get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ItemsControl creates it's own parent panel to display the items in.  By default, this is a StackPanel [which you can see here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/ef9004fa94ddb0013412816d58e924464723d9f2/src/Avalonia.Controls/ItemsControl.cs#L28).  So what you actually have is a Canvas that contains a rectangle and a StackPanel, and that StackPanel contains 3 more rectangles.

You can change the panel with the `ItemsPanel` property.  However, you won't be able to add your blue rectangle to this canvas in XAML. You might want to add it to your items collection and bind the color to a property in the object.

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" >
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="100" Background="Yellow" Margin="3" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="{Binding Size}" Width="{Binding Size}" Canvas.Left="{Binding TopY}" Canvas.Top="{Binding TopY}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks it's almost correct, you also need to use the a style to be able to set position the rectangle correctly. See my discussion in Avalonia repo https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/14296 Could you complete your answer with the style section and I'll accept it as the answer?